# Recursive filesystem notifications (inotify) for Ubuntu Karmic Koala

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, recursive

I need a program which generates events when a file is moved, removed or its extended attributes are changed. I'm running Ubuntu Karmic Koala 32-bit desktop.

*inotify* is the standard solution for such problems, but inotify cannot install a recursive watch, so the only option is to the equivalent of `find` on the filesystem, and add an inotify watch on each node. This is what e.g. `inotifywatch` does. This won't work for me, because my filesystem has 1 million files, and installing watches to all of them takes forever.

*fanotify* could work except that I would have to patch the kernel for that (I'm currently running 2.6.31-20), and maintaining patches to the Linux kernel is beyond my time commitment.

I used to use *rfsdelta* (whose kernel module is similar to *rlocate*), but it just doesn't compile on 2.6.31, because it uses obsolete Linux security framework APIs.

I suspect that on-demand antivirus software on Linux might use some other technique I don't know of.

Comment: have you found a solution to the problem? I also want to see what happens in my os in realtime-ish manner ... hope such trivial thing is possible to do in super-duper linux os!

Comment: No, I haven't found heard of anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too intense traffic on the structure you want to monitor, you might be interested in iwatch, which takes care of placing listeners recursively.

http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html

Careful though, since if file system events are very close AND trying to create a deep structure (ex: a/b/c/d/e/f), you might not pick all the events due to race conditions.

See here for more info:

http://old.nabble.com/Bug-494397%3A-iwatch%3A-New-subdirectories-in-recursive-mode-won%27t-be-recognized-p27145632.html

Comment: That's a wrapper around `inotify`. It's therefore bound by the same restrictions, i.e. it cannot handle a million files either.

Comment: True, although it is a one off cost. The real problem (or so it seems to me) is that `inotify` doesn't support recursive watch. While `inotifywatch` does provide this feature, it doesn't support action triggers. The correct way to use `inotify` is not to set a watch on each file but instead on folders anyway and I strongly doubt the OP had 1 million folders.

Comment: I need solution which is fast to load (at reboot) and doesn't have race conditions. My filesystem indeed has about 1 million files in 10000 folders. Thus `iwatch` and `inotifywatch` don't work for me.